# How does firewalld handle packet state internally when you add rules?

Tags: iptables, firewalld

Coming from an `iptables` background, I can specify packet connection states (usually either `NEW` and/or `ESTABLISHED`) when defining new firewall rules. For example, this pair of rules will ensure that `http` connections will only be allowed when initiated by my host and dropped when initiated by remote hosts:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

However, when I started exploring `firewalld` as an alternative, I wasn't able to find much documentation on states apart from firewalld is a stateful firewall management service, and that it seems to be handling the packet states internally somehow. Can someone help to explain whether it is possible to define packet states (like in the `iptables` example above) when creating firewall rules using `firewalld`? Else, how do we implement something to the same effect when using `firewalld`?

Comment: The case where RELATED needs specific rules is when an helper protocol is enabled (eg: FTP with the `nf_conntrack_ftp` module) but one wants to restrict the results of this helper. Then there would be a rule restricting addresses or more probably ports  with a `--ctstate RELATED -m helper --helper ftp` with an accept target. followed by the same rule without filters and same `--ctstate RELATED -m helper --helper ftp` with a drop target. And third and last a generic `--ctstate RELATED` with an accept target to allow for example ICMP errors. No idea if firewalld can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--direct` rules with `firewall-cmd` command. In your case, the commands to execute may look like this:

```
# Check for existing firewalld direct rules
$ sudo firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules
# Now add your direct rule
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp --dport=80 -j ACCEPT -m state --state NEW
# Return traffic (ESTABLISHED for example) is automatically allowed due to firewalld's stateful nature
# Reload firewalld
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
# Check if your direct rule was successfully added
$ sudo firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules
# From server side create a listening port (if there is no service listening on TCP 80)
$ nc -vlt 80
# From client side, initiate a connection to server on port 80
# Where X.X.X.X is server IP or hostname (with a 3 seconds timeout)
$ nc -v -w 3 X.X.X.X 80
```

References: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/using_the_direct_interface

Answer (score 0):

It does *not* make a lot of sense to specify `ESTABLISHED`,`RELATED` states separately, for each specific rule, as most manuals, tutorials and firewalld simply create these three rules and put them at the top of the respective INPUT/OUTPUT/FORWARD chains:

```
iptables -A INPUT   -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT  -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

For nft that would be:
`ct state { established, related } accept`

I can barely imagine the situation when you do not use these global rules: maybe for testing the TCP/IP stack but in this case you'd be better off without any predefined rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Artem. I did a bit more research and found that while I can't specify `-m state --state` or `ct state` using `firewall-cmd` directly, the corresponding iptables/nftables rules generated by the `firewall-cmd` command end up having some sort of state being specified. I guess packet states are handled automatically when using `firewalld` and we can't control directly.